# Flaky `ApplicationSyntaxReference` on `AttributeData` with (Incremental) Source Generator

Tags: roslyn, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

Unfortunately, I have no minimal sample of the issue, but I've pushed the repo publicly, where it should be reproducable: https://github.com/Yeah69/ContainerFeatureSampleComparison

I've implemented a source generator, which iterates through the referenced assemblies and tries to extract the code of files which have a specific attribute. The code extraction looks like this:

```cs
var sampleText = attributeData.ApplicationSyntaxReference is {} a 
    ? a.GetSyntax().GetLocation().SourceTree is {} b 
        ? b.GetText().ToString()
        : "InnerNull"
    : "OuterNull";
```

In certain situations this works fine, in others not. Therefore, I assume a strange flakyness here.

I use Rider as the IDE for development and the .Net SDK 7.0.302 (if that matters).

The output shown in the IDE Source Generator listing works fine:
[image: Does work for the IDE Source Generator Output]

The file generated with `EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles` however is faulty:
[image: Doesn't work for file generated by EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles]
Same situation when the Release-version of the `Composition`-project is executed. `attributeData.ApplicationSyntaxReference` being `null` in the faulty situations has to be the error. But it riddles me what would cause it, because for the IDE output it seems to work fine. I appreciate any help with this issue.

Comment: In what way is it faulty?

Comment: I expected the code generated in the second snippet to be the same as in the first snippet. That means instead of the "OuterNull" strings it should have strings that contain the appropriate code (the code of the files where the associated attribute is in).

The snippets show two differently located files. One is the Source Generator Preview Feature of Rider (VS has a similar feature, I think). The other is emitted by the Roslyn compiler. But their contents should be identical, as they use the same generator on the same set of assemblies. Why does it work in one place but not in the other?

Comment: However, I've found a workaround, yesterday. Not quite sure, if it is worth being an answer to this issue, so I just leave it for now. My workaround is to split the previously single generator into two generators. The new generator is used on the referenced assembly directly and extracts the code files which contain instances of the attribute. That way it always works, not just for the preview feature.